# unable to view new table data after concat - Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic's events to pass data from page to page. In this instance I'm passing an array to another page, let's say with two objects. The data I'm wanting to add to is called dataOne and I'm using a life cycle function so that when the user enters the page they will be automatically tested from this function whether or not there is an event to be concatenated onto dataOne. The issue is, the data isn't being added. I'm able to retrieve the data but nothing happens to the table, as I'm still getting the same result.

ts

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.events.subscribe('market', (dataTwo) => {
            return this.dataOne = this.dataOne.concat(dataTwo)
          })
}
```

Comment: Why not you register event emitter receiver code in constructor method? because its enough to register once and no need to register every time when you enter in to the page right?? Let me know if you have different kind  of requirement..

Answer (score 0):

What is 'Market' ? dataOne is array? In my opinion,

```
dataOne: any[]=[];
...
this.events.subscribe((dataTwo) =>{
 this.dataOne.push(dataTwo.market); // if market you want to catch data
}
```